# Passing jquery slider value into function

Tags: jquery, slider

I am trying to capture the value from my jQuery slider and pass it into another function. I have seen some examples for this but I am trying to pass it into a function that has multiple parameters in it. Here is my slider code:

```
    $("#slider_font_size").slider({

            min: 1,
            max: 3,
            step: 1,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                TredWareApp.FONT_SIZE = ui.value;
                drawTextOnTire();
            },
            value: TredWareApp.FONT_SIZE,

            orientation: 'horizontal'
        });
```

And this is the function that I want to pass it into:

```
    function drawTextAlongArc(context, str, centerX, centerY, radius, angle, height) {

    var len = str.length, s;
    context.save();

    context.translate(centerX, centerY);
    context.rotate(-1 * angle / 2);
    context.rotate(-1 * (angle / len) / 2);

   for (var n = 0; n < len; n++) {

        context.rotate(angle / len);
        context.save();
        context.translate(0, -1 * radius);

        s = str[n];
       //context.fillText(s, 0, 0);
        var imageText = document.getElementById(s + "1");
        context.drawImage(imageText,0,0, 30, height*15);

        context.restore();

    }

    context.restore();

}
```

I want to pass it is as the height value. I call this above function here:

```
    drawTextAlongArc(ctx, $("#tiretext").val(), centerX, centerY, radius, angle, $("#slider_font_size").val());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get value of slider like this:

```
$("#slider_font_size").slider("value");
```

JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cZPcX/

Comment: The problem I am having is making the sliderValue available to be called outside of the slider function.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you... Have you tried to call your function like this?
 drawTextAlongArc(ctx, $("#tiretext").val(), centerX, centerY, radius, angle, $("#slider_font_size").slider("value"));

Comment: Sorry I didn't make that very clear but I got it got it called the way you suggested but it is one behind on the slider value. So when I am at the second value it is still on the first value. Does that make sense?

Comment: Can you send me a link so I can check source? Or put your example on JSFiddle